# How do I change UI language more effieicntly?

Tags: codenameone

I changed the UI language by code below

```
UIManager.getInstance().setBundle(theme.getL10N("L10N", language));
```

Should I recreate all components on the UI to change the language?

Are there any more efficient methodologies to change languages on all the UI components?

Comment: Does [this Localization](https://github.com/Eric-Chomba/FeaturesCN1-Maven/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/zomuhtech/cn/features/advft/LocalizationFt.java) implementation help? When you change language in Localization menu, hint label languages in [Sqlite menu](https://github.com/Eric-Chomba/FeaturesCN1-Maven/blob/master/common/src/main/java/com/zomuhtech/cn/features/advft/SQLiteStore.java) also change.

Comment: What is FeaturesCN1-Maven for?

Comment: See [ReadMe](https://github.com/Eric-Chomba/FeaturesCN1-Maven/blob/master/README.adoc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. No.

There's no way that's more efficient since the alternative is to bind all components to a listener that would track language changes. This can be expensive but also risks a memory leak. Forms are meant to be fast to create and discard in Codename One, so this should be pretty fast.